# Absolute position element WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I want to position a cross button in the top right of my dialog without it affecting the flow of the rest of the dialog, this seems to be rather difficult when commpared to CSS?

This currently aligned the content about 20px from the right hand side because its still in column 0 and column 1 is occupying that space.  Ideally all the content would be within a `StackPanel` with the close button being positioned top right.  Failing that I guess it may be possible to make the content span the two columns? How do I fix this?

Here is my current XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="UI_DialogTitle" Style="{StaticResource i2_TitleTextBlock}" Text="{TemplateBinding DialogTitle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DialogTitleVisibility}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TheContentPresenter"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="UI_CloseDialog" Style="{StaticResource i2_CloseDialogButton}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you add an abstract image showing how is current rendering and required rendering and I am not getting what is your problem in que.. `The close button` or `StackPanel Content` ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Grid.ColumnSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan.aspx) property?

Comment: Indeed I am / was - will post code that made it all work

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed the `ColumnSpan` property - this all works now!

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock x:Name="UI_DialogTitle" Style="{StaticResource i2_TitleTextBlock}" Text="{TemplateBinding DialogTitle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DialogTitleVisibility}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TheContentPresenter"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="UI_CloseDialog" Style="{StaticResource i2_CloseDialogButton}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. Check the btnClose and the screenshot.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="SlateGray" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="12" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="20" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CC4895DE" Offset="0.844"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF346592" Offset="0.393"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBox Height="26" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Margin="0,0,30,220" Name="txtQuotationNumber" Width="332" />

        </Border>
        **<Button Margin="0,4,4,0" Click="OKButton_Click" Cursor="Hand" x:Name="btnClose" Style="{StaticResource CloseStyleX}" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Close Popup"/>**

        -- Datagrid here
        -- COMBOBOX HERE

        <TextBox Height="26" Name="txtValue" IsTabStop="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="178,10,500,0"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Search" Click="btnSearch_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,37,0" Name="btnSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
    </Grid>
```

[image]